# GNU C Extensions documentation: where is it?

Tags: c, gnu

I know there are several language extensions added in the **GNU C compiler** (aka gcc).
I can read something about that [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/index.html#toc_C-Extensions).

What I'm looking for is deeper and wider documentation about those topics.

For example I'd like to read more about _Static_assert(), typeof and the likes.

Maybe it's just my fault, but I cannot find such an official documentation. Any hint? TIA!

Comment: On my ubuntu says it has not "Top" node! I've also installed gcc-doc and texinfo stuff ... Nope! Isn't there any online doc?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ or, more directly, http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions

Comment: That link is more or less the same I mentioned earlier...

Comment: @Enzo typeof is documented at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof , and _Static_assert is a C11 feature.

Comment: @Enzo I didn't bother to check your link. That **is** the official documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html and you're not finding about static assertions because it's not an extension of the C language, it's a core, built-in, standardized part of the language and described in the language international standards. In this case, refer to the C specification:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

See section 6.7.10 Static assertions, in particular paragraph 3:

"The constant expression shall be an integer constant expression. If the value of the
constant expression compares unequal to 0, the declaration has no effect. Otherwise, the
constraint is violated and the implementation shall produce a diagnostic message that
includes the text of the string literal, except that characters not in the basic source
character set are not required to appear in the message."

Comment: This very one is the closer answer to my question. Which is largely unanswered, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html.

Use Google to search inside gnu.org. Found it by typing this search in Google: `c extensions site:gnu.org`.

Comment: I typed gnu.org extensions "_Static_assert" and got no documentation, even without the "extensions" keyword. The best match is a changelog for v4.6 with no usage details.

Comment: If you mean http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/changes.html, then it says it's an experimental extension for the C1X revision. Assume it's supporting the official C1X syntax and play with it. Note the big warning in the changelog that it may change in the future. I also updated the syntax to search inside a site.